# What is the format, or what the parameters look like to get a token on https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v2/auth/token on SABRE

Tags: api, token, sabre

I'm trying to build an app to connect to Sabre rest api.
So far, I'm trying to get a token using postman, but feels like I'm missing a lot of parameters:
Here what my call looks like 'Retrieved using Code to Jquery'

```js
var settings = {
  "url": "https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v1",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  "data": {
    "grant_type": "password",
    "Client_ID": "myclientidgoeshereinthisspace",
    "client_secret": "myclientsecretgoeshere"
  }
};
    
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following link which provides details on how to generate the token:-

https://developer.sabre.com/guides/travel-agency/quickstart-guides/get-token

Step 1: Get Your Sabre Credentials. Your Sabre credentials get you access to the Sabre GDS. (Get your Sabre credentials from your Sabre account manager, or get free credentials by creating a Dev Studio account.)

Step 2: Construct Your Token Credentials.

Step 3: Get a Token.

Also REST API customers must first construct a single base64-encoded string. There are two recommended options to construct the REST API session less token credentials in REST API Token Credentials. Here is a link which explains the same:-

https://developer.sabre.com/guides/travel-agency/developer-guides/rest-apis-token-credentials

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure what is the error you are getting, but the URL you have there is wrong, it should be the one you have on the subject. Although I see that there's [a new v3 now](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/session_management/token_create_api/reference-documentation#/Create%20ATK/atkWithClientCredentialsAndId).

I don't think that you can send Client_ID and client_secret in the body, it might be required (for some specrific purpose) as a header.

And it is a MUST the credentials, that you don't seem to be passing

So, assuming that the call works, try the following (updating your credentials)

```
var settings = {
  "url": "https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v3/auth/token",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authentication": `Basic btoa(`${btoa('ClientID')}:${btoa('ClientSecret')}`)`
  },
  "data": {
    "grant_type": "password"
  }
};
```

You can use the test credentials you have on DevStudio: https://developer.sabre.com/user/YOUR_USER/applications